# SQL Database Timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, timestamp

I have a database where people register on a website and their form data then gets inserted into their database. Along with all that information, I want to insert the time of their registration. For example I have an auto-incrementing ID column which I do nothing in my php script for, the sql database automatically increments that with every new entry. In the same way, can I have a time column that I don't have to do anything in the script for, rather the database will just get the current time and put that along with the other inserted information? I'm using phpMyAdmin and I tried adding a column named Time with the type as `DATETIME` and the default value as the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` but it woulnd't let me add that and said invalid default value for Time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the [column type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) to `TIMESTAMP`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [timestamp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/datetime.html) field, which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1):

use `timestamp` column type e.g.

```
`inserted` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```